# How to draw on image in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm coding an application with xamarin forms and I've a problem. 
The goal is to have an image (from an api), detect the touch event when the user touches the screen on this image and then, draw something like an icon on the image with the coordinates catched by the touch event.

I didn't find any component that allow me to do that. Has someone an idea?

Thanks

Comment: is your image too big , and u want to touch and drag (pan gesture) to see it fully ? if yes, there are many examples on net , search for pan gesture in Xamarin forms

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/190529#Comment_190529

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad/

https://github.com/15mgm15/Xamarin-Forms-Signature

You can set an Image for the background and use the signature pad to draw in front of it.

Comment: I am doing the same but the image and signature are not matching